# Select multiple file to upload as populated in html table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to find the number of the file selected as file selection tag is populated in an HTML table every row with a button. 
I just want to find out the file count (total selected files) when clicking on same row button and upload all selected files

The following code gives an error.

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

```js
function saveValue(data) {
  var fileU = $(data).closest('tr').find('input[type=file]');
  var count = files.length;
  console.log(count);
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var file = fileU[i].files[0];
    console.log(file)
    formData.append("files[]", file);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="">
      <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Attached Letter"><input type="file" class='files' name="files[]" multiple></p>
    </td>
    <td width="40%"><button class="btnSelect" onclick='saveValue(this);'> Count </button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet - please make it run as a [mcve]

Comment: You are counting files instead of fileU.length and are missing  `formData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line throws an error

```
var count = files.length;
```

`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"` means that variable `files` is not defined anywhere.

try to to define it, like this for example:

```
var files = fileU[0].files;
var count = files.length;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: `var count = fileU.length;` and formData is missing too. Not interesting to answer typo type questions

Comment: well, yeah. I assume that there is just one input in a row, so `var files = fileU[0].files;` also should work, later we will loop it

Comment: `formData` is missing also, that's why I provided not a full snippet, but only answer related to `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. For a one like you I totally agree, it could be not interesting

Comment: For no one except OP. He needs to fix such things first and provide a [mcve] - there will be more issues since he seems to have an uploadt per row